# Cannot read property 'location' of undefined in React Router example

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Trying to do the most simple example possible with React Router.
Every example I've looked at is very different and many include 20 page tutorials. I just want a simple root path to work:

```
...
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-router/umd/react-router.min.js"></script>
...

var insert_point = document.querySelector('#container');

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Stuff</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactRouter.Router>
    <ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={App}>
    </ReactRouter.Route>
  </ReactRouter.Router>,
  insert_point
);
```

[image]

Comment: What react router version?

Comment: it is 4.1.1 (see added above)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're in the browser, you'll need [`react-router-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) too, a separate package in v4. `react-router` only contains the core, but for the DOM bindings you need the former package:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Then, get what you need from the global `ReactRouterDOM`. I find it easier just to use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get what you need:

```
var { BrowserRouter, Route } = ReactRouterDOM;
```

Then you can do:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

The problem was that you weren't using the correct router -- for the web use `BrowserRouter`. Then, use `Route` and make sure to include the `exact` prop to only match the root route, in this case you can make `Route` self closing.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is in how are you importing react router. When working with webpack I am using react-router-dom package and BrowserRouter

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
```

Which are correct packages for V4. So at least I think you should use [cdn that provides react-router-dom](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/4.1.1/react-router-dom.js)

also Try to use BrowserRouter instead of Router.

Aside from this, you can close your Route component immediately

```
<ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={App}/>
```

Also I do not understand your intentions with `insertion_point` as they are in your code.